# how to initialize my ldap connection like a doctrine connection in the bootstrap.php file in zend-framework

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, doctrine

i want to use my ldap server as a DB. then i will create persistence classes in the models directory that will extend to Zend_Ldap so that i won't have to write all the CRUD operations but how can i initialize the ldap connection in the bootstrap.php file
for e.g. a database connection using doctrine can be initialized like this, i want to do the same for ldap connection

```
protected function _initDoctrine()
 {
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('Doctrine');
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
        ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));

    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $doctrineConfig = $this->getOption('doctrine');
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

    Doctrine_Core::loadModels($doctrineConfig['models_path']);

    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($doctrineConfig['dsn'],'doctrine');
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
 return $conn;
}
```

but now what i want to do is if i have some thing like this(below) in the models folder

```
class Application_Model_entry extends Zend_Ldap_Node_collection {

public static function getInstance() {
    $options = Zend_Registry::get('config')->ldap;//i want to avoid this line
    $ldap = new Zend_Ldap($options); // i want to avoid this line
    $dn = $ldap->getBaseDn(); // i want to avoid this line

    $a = new Zend_Ldap_Node_Collection(new Zend_Ldap_Collection_Iterator_Default($ldap,'email')); //also this one 
    return $a;//where $a is an instance of an LDAP entry(node)

}
```

then in the controller i want to do some thing like a db

```
$ent = new Application_Model_entry();
$ent->email = "xyz@abc.xom";
...
$ent->save();
$ent->update();
```

how can i initialize the ldap connection and access it in the models so that this could be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
protected function _initLdap() 
{
    $ldap = new Zend_Ldap(/*... your configuration ...*/);
    return $ldap;
}
```

But there is no such thing as a *default* LDAP connection, so you have to retrieve the LDAP connection object from your bootstrap's resources. Some helper class may, well, help.

By the way your model should not extend `Zend_Ldap` - at least not for the reason you want to do this. You could e.g. extend `Zend_Ldap_Node` which is a representation of a single LDAP entry, whilst `Zend_Ldap` is a representation of the LDAP connection and the LDAP server you're talking to.

**EDIT:**

```
class Application_Ldap
{
    public static function getLdap()
    {
        /* return LDAP connection from bootstrap */
    }

    public static function newEntry($name) 
    {
        $dn   = $name; // build DN from given entity name
        $node = Zend_Ldap_Node::create($dn);
        $node->attachLdap(self::getLdap());
        return $node;
    }

    public static function loadEntry($name)
    {
        $dn   = $name; // build DN from given entity name
        $node = Zend_Ldap_Node::fromLdap($dn, self::getLdap());
        return $node
    }
}
```

Be advised: this is not really a state-of-the-art model, but just a simple solution to your problem (if I understood it correctly). It allows you to do the following in your application logic:

```
$newOne = Application_Ldap::newEntry('new-one');
$newOne->email = "xyz@abc.xom";
$newOne->update();

$oldOne = Application_Ldap::loadEntry('old-one');
$oldOne->email = "abc@abc.xom";
$oldOne->update();
```

Comment: i have tried that one. but could you explain your answer i didn't get you when you say "But there is no such thing as a default LDAP connection, so you have to retrieve the LDAP connection object from your bootstrap's resources. Some helper class may, well, help......... " b/se i want to avoid the lines i indicated above by moving them to the bootstrap.php file as you indicated. even though i moved that line to the bootstrap.php file already how can i access the connection objection in same way as doctrine or so .. in the models @Stefan Gehrig

Comment: What I meant by *But there is no such thing as a default LDAP connection* is, that while Doctrine maintains a static global reference (using a singleton) to the default database connection and uses this reference inside the generated models to allow interaction with the database without specifying a distinct connection each time, `Zend_Ldap` itself does not have such a concept by its own. It was not designed to be some kind of object-relational-mapper, table-gateway or row-gateway for LDAP-based data. It can be compared to what `Zend_Db` does in its core: provide an interface into the...

Comment: ... database connection. I'll extend my answer to show a possible approach.

Reading your edits, I tink you should have a depper look at what `Zend_Ldap`, `Zend_Ldap_Node` and `Zend_Ldap_Node_Collection` represent. You're mixing up these entities.